# attempt to index global 'GameDatabase' (a nil value) - (A Garrysmod script)

Tags: lua, garrys-mod

Im a bit stuck on figuring out why this is not working. I have not done anything to the code so im a bit curious to why it would no longer work. Any help is appreciated. Here are the errors im getting:

```
    [ERROR] gamemodes/harborrp/gamemode/data.lua:59: attempt to index global 'GameDatabase' (a nil value)
  1. Query - gamemodes/harborrp/gamemode/data.lua:59
   2. unknown - gamemodes/harborrp/gamemode/sv_gamemode_functions.lua:790
    3. UniqueID - [C]:-1
     4. echoToAdmins - addons/ulx/lua/ulx/log.lua:164
      5. fn - addons/ulx/lua/ulx/log.lua:202
       6. unknown - addons/ulib/lua/ulib/shared/hook.lua:110




[ERROR] gamemodes/harborrp/gamemode/data.lua:158: attempt to index global 'GameDatabase' (a nil value)
  1. QueryValue - gamemodes/harborrp/gamemode/data.lua:158
   2. LoadInventory - gamemodes/harborrp/gamemode/inventory/sv_inventory.lua:41
    3. fn - gamemodes/harborrp/gamemode/inventory/sv_inventory.lua:58
     4. unknown - addons/ulib/lua/ulib/shared/hook.lua:110




[ERROR] gamemodes/harborrp/gamemode/data.lua:158: attempt to index global 'GameDatabase' (a nil value)
  1. QueryValue - gamemodes/harborrp/gamemode/data.lua:158
   2. unknown - gamemodes/harborrp/gamemode/sv_gamemode_functions.lua:1068
```

Here's are locations it's referring to:

Line 58:

```
function DB.Query(query, callback, qtype)

local cBackFunc = function(r)
    if r[1].error then
        local err = table.concat({"tMySQL query error: ", r[1].error, debug.Trace() or "", "Query: ", query, "\n"}, "")
        DB.Log(err)
        ErrorNoHalt(err)
        r[1].data = nil
        //return
    end
    // lua_run DB.Query("SELECT amount, steam, rpname FROM metrorp_wallets limit 3", PrintTable, 1)
    if callback then
        if qtype == 0 then
            ErrorNoHalt("Query "..query.." used Type 0 in DB.Query!\n")
            local tbl = {}
            for i=1, #r[1].data do
                local ind = 1
                tbl[i] = {}
                for a,b in pairs(r[1].data[i]) do
                    tbl[i][ind] = b
                    ind = ind + 1
                end
            end
            callback(tbl, !r[1].error)
        else
            callback(r[1].data, !r[1].error)
        end
    end

end
GameDatabase:Query(query, cBackFunc)
```

end

Line 158:

```
function DB.QueryValue(query, callback)
local function cBack(r)
    if !r or !r[1].data or !r[1].data[1] then
        callback(nil, !r[1].error)
        return
    end
    local ind = next(r[1].data[1])
    callback(r[1].data[1][ind], !r[1].error)
end
GameDatabase:Query(query, callback and cBack)
```

end

Answer (score 0):

GameDatabase is nil. It could be that you're trying to run this code clientside when GameDatabase is only declared serverside. You can put an `if SERVER then` check around shared code to only make it run serverside.